# Why is Boolean “hole” filled with stripes?

Tags: mesh, modifiers, objects

I'm new to using Booleans in Blender and I'm trying to add cylindrical holes into a solid ceiling to accommodate recessed lighting. The problem is that some of the "holes" I created are solid? Or capped? When rendered in Cycles, the blue ceiling material turns into blue & gray stripes in the Booleaned region. Something's going on, but I can't figure out what. Any suggestions? Thanks. Windows 10, Blender 3.0.0

[image]

**Update #2:** As I research this I'm realizing that there's a lot to learn. I'm doubting that there's a simple answer to this issue. :)

**Update:** I've tried this by using cube and cylinder primitives, but no matter what I try, the cube seems to be hollowed out in the interior, but the surface of the cube has circular "caps" over the hole. I tried solidifying the cube before the Boolean operation, but the result is the same.

Comment: It looks as if your boolean cutter isn't actually going through the ceiling. Try moving it down or scaling it on the Z axis and see what happens. If you still don't have any luck, upload your Blend file here so that someone can have a look.

Comment: John Eason, thank you for the response. I think I've figured it out. The Boolean operand was plenty long enough; the problem was that I wasn't hiding it after the Difference operation, so I didn't think it was doing anything. The other thing that confused me was Justin Geis' informative 2020 video (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QNvbz-lz4ho) where his Blender Boolean modifier interface is different from my version 3.0.

Comment: If you install the built-in Bool tool addon (Edit > Preferences > Addons and search for 'Bool') you can then use CTRL + Numpad keys to automatically add a boolean modifier and the modifier object's viewport mode will be changed to 'Bounds' at the same time which makes things much clearer. There's a video [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Rmvl0xVsA_o) which shows how to install and use it. That's for Blender 2.8 but it works the same way in 2.9 and 3.0.

Comment: John Eason, thank you again for the tip and for the link!

Comment: No problem. Happy Blendering!